# Getting started with mobile programming. What is a good platform?

Tags: java, android, c++

What is a good mobile programming platform to go with for a `c++` developer?

Is learning `android` a good option?

Comment: I recommend you using android studio because google will support it

Answer (score 8):

If you already know C++ then Symbian has the largest install base, and isn't sandboxed like java/android vm/iphone.

Whilst the iPhone and Andriod may seem interesting, if you actually look at the figures Symbian really is the only option when looking at market share. Despite apple's advertising behemoth and cult following, it is far from being anywhere near the 200+ million Symbian smart phones out there. (there are approx 5 million iphone users).

Added to the fact that "java" on mobiles doesn't always mean the same thing. Different phones include different versions so unlike the PC environment, java on mobiles is not as "write once, run anywhere" as it makes out.

Answer (score 4):

I have started playing with Android with the [latest SDK](http://code.google.com/android/download.html). It is super easy to develop because of the coolness of Java, richness of android platform and [eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) is very easy to use. I think Android is going to make a big difference in the moile application side.

UPDATE : Now you have the option of Windows Phone 7 too, which is my favorite at this point because I am a .NET developer for many years. Just get the [WP7SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en) and start coding in your visual studio itself.

Answer (score 2):

[Java ME](http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp) will give you the widest choice of deployment options and market share, because most mobile phones support it.  Going from C++ to Java is quite easy, since Java has fewer gotchas than C++.  As a positive side effect you will also get to learn Java on a platform whose footprint is a lot smaller and manageable than [Java SE](http://java.sun.com/javase/).

Comment: "Most phones support it" - yes, but what derivative of 'it' they support isn't always the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice the [.NET Compact Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework) for easy and fast development. The included emulator in Visual Studio makes it that much easier to develop.

But I also think that it depends on your intended application, I would for instance not advice the compact framework for writing a game with demanding graphics.

The downside of using the .NET Compact Framework is that you'll get limited on your target hardware, because it will only run on Microsoft Windows CE versions (and I thought on SymbianOS).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I started out with the Windows Mobile platform and Microsoft Embedded C++.

It was a natural shift because I'd come from the MSVC compiler/Visual Studio 6 environment, so I was already quite familiar with aspects of the compiler and the IDE.

In fact, because I was so familiar with those other tools, picking up the emulator and (notably) the oddities of working with ActiveSync became much easier.  I also found the OS to be easy to use (including the familiar File Explorer and system design).

So, to more accurately answer your question, I think it depends on which platform you are familiar with previously and how confident you feel with the tools available.  Especially for debugging and emulating!

Answer (score 0):

in Symbian you can reach all the phone functionality == do really cool things, but Symbian is a bitch when you are trying to learn it from scratch - it's complicated.

JavaME - popular, very quick to start, light API, but sandboxed, access to different phone areas varies from vendor to vendor, from model to model. You can do stuff like connect to net, draw graphics and display menus on pretty every phone, but access to phone book, camera, sms messaging varies greatly

Sometimes it takes time to get app working exactly the same on different phone models (i don't know exactly, but i think this would be a problem on all the mobile platforms)

Answer (score 0):

You surely need to check out Windows Phone 7, it is C# and have great tool support with VS2010 and Expression blend to develop quick Windows Phone applications. Not only this will benefit you in Phone. The same dev-skill set can be used to make Silverlight as well as WPF applications easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use StartJava which illustrate Android application creation.

http://www.en.assoft.ru/startjava

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.assoft.StartJava

Answer (score 0):

I want suggest you android is best technology among all now a days android phones are increasing tremendously so the development are also increasing like wise and it can be learn any developer...on the internet many tutorials are available to teach you android programming....so i would like to suggest you is that android is the best option...